# Как создавать сайт с текстом для сео?

Tags: javascript, html, seo

Я всегда пишу сайт, где в `html` лишь одна строка

```
<div id = 'main'></div>
```

а далее я все делаю через `javascript`, к примеру

```
document.getElementById('main').innerhtml = '<div class = 'text'>какой-то текст</div>';
```

В нем могут быть кнопка и прочее, и далее так подгружаю тексты, либо с бд, либо напрямую иногда писал в таком коде. Сайт работает, но для сео он невидимка. Я не пойму, как правильно создать сайт, чтобы сео его видел? Писать много html-кода, а так подгружать через js неправильно? Направьте меня пожалуйста в нужном направлении, пока не нашел ответа на мой вопрос.

Comment: 1) Поисковые боты вполне себе могут индексировать динамическое содержимое. Так что проблема не обязательно непосредственно в его динамичности. 2) в 80% случаев js не нужен

Comment: я бы попытался ответить, но слишком много нюансов. проще сесть и с нуля начать углубляться в **SEO**

Comment: То есть, по своей сути, что использование чистого js, что фреймворков не влияет на оптимизацию сайта?

Comment: @нет, не влияет. но есть еще нюанс где это всё рендерится (собирается) - на сервере (**SSR**) или на клиенте (**CSR**). ходят легенды, что страница, собранная на сервере, намного лучше поддается для **SEO**

Answer (score -1):

Поисковые роботы обходят не код вашего проекта на сервере, а сформированные кодом страницы, содержащие контент и структуру. И если в вашем проекте к отдельному адресу привязан свой контент, то всё будет нормально индексироваться, все php сайты работают по такому принципу! Важно только, что бы на страницах присутствовали важные для индексации элементы: h1, h2, title... Если помог поставьте пожалуйста "принять ответ")))